# JSTL: How to access table row contents using index

Tags: mysql, jstl

My question is: 
**How can I access row information using index in JSTL?** i am using MySQL 5.1.47 Server as Relational Database Server

For example,
I have a table name **login** with two attributes “**username**” & “**password**” and this table contain 10 records. I want to extract only first record information. How can I do this?   I have checked on many website and could find only one way to iterate through table using For Each Tag, as follow

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${query1.rows}">
<c:set var='dbUserName' value="${row.loginID}"/>  
<c:set var='dbUserPassword' value="${row.password}"/>  
</c:forEach>
```

Using **For Each is not helpful in accessing row information by index**.  Kindly Suggest or let me know if there is a very good resource on JSTL Database funcationality.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please register your user account. You have two another unregistered accounts with unaccepted questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/414169/sohail and http://stackoverflow.com/users/414161/sohail  If you register your account, you will be able to login on different PC's and browsers and keep a history of your questions and have access to those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the backing object, you can probably use a simple array index, such as:

```
${query1.rows[0].loginID}
```